# What happened to the Mighty Orbots cartoon series?

Tags: mighty-orbots

I loved The [Mighty Orbots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Orbots) show when it was broadcast decades ago. It lasted only one season and ended with a finale episode, which is unusual for cartoons. Was it always planned as a one-season show? It doesn't appear to have ever been released on DVD - why did it just disappear?

Comment: So who owns the rights now??? I have an idea: We need to create a game based on Mighty Orbots. It could be a video game or a board game, but the primary goal would be to get as much publicity for it as possible. Once it becomes popular, the original owners of the MO rights will A) see the value of the property and/or B) contact us with a cease & desist order. Either way, we will know who to contact at that point. Any one interested?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Orbots), the 13-episode series was never released on DVD. It ended early

> due to a lawsuit between the show's creators and toymaker Tonka, who
>   accused them of basing the cartoon on their GoBots franchise (which
>   was adapted from Bandai's Machine Robo line). The robot depicted in
>   the show was virtually identical to the robot in the anime for
>   Bandai's Godmars toy, although the colors were changed.

This may have affected its release.

According to a rather informative review [here](http://www.anime-games.co.uk/VHS/anime/orbots1.php), poor ratings were its downfall, though its release in other markets on VHS developed a small cult following. T M S Entertainment, Inc./M G M/U A Entertainment Company is the copyright holder according to US Copyright office. If you have access to a VCR, there are a couple of libraries in the US that apparently have it in their collections (set of 13 tapes). You might be able to get your local library to do an inter-library loan for you.

Comment: Wikipedia has been known to be wrong.  Is there any visual evidence to back the image of the Godmars toy to Mighty Orbot?  Having typed this, do know that my next step is to go search for one online.

Comment: From what I've seen so far in my short investigation, Tonka sued because the word "Orbots" from "Mighty Orbots" was too phonetically close to "GoBots", which used the phrase "Mighty robots, mighty vehicles" as their slogan.  The Mighty Orbots primary robot did form like Bandai's God Mars toy (or Godmars, depending on who you ask), but that was possibly intended as a way to bring God Mars to the US, and the comment regarding the similarity is appears to be independent of and irrelevant to the lawsuit.  Of note, Hasbro now owns GoBots, so there shouldn't be anything left preventing release.

Comment: OK, from http://well-of-souls.com/orbots/about.htm : `There was also a lawsuit filed by Tonka alleging that the Orbots somehow infringed on their Go-Bots property that probably didn't help. {...} Tonka was a licensee of Bandai's Machine Robo line, and apparently had rights to GodMarz. The combined Mighty Orbots robot was a near-duplicate of the combined GodMarz robot, so even though GodMarz was not itself featured in the Go-Bots line, this may have been a pre-emptive lawsuit, and perhaps not entirely without merit.`

Comment: Apparently Hasbro now owns the GoBots fiction, but the license for the toy likenesses are back with Bandai.  This means... ??? for a DVD release of the cartoon?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  Of note, this doesn't answer the overall investigative questions of (1) who holds the cartoon now and (2) why haven't they released it, considering the lawsuit shouldn't be stopping them at this time.  I'm sure it's demand, but it'd be nice to know.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Bandai Customer Service...

> Hi, I loved the Might Orbots as a kid and would like a DVD release please.
>
> 1-It looks like Bandai holds the license for the Mighty Orbots
> 2-Will you please release the 13 episodes to DVD?
>
> Please let me know.

...and got this response a week later...

> Thank you for your inquiry.
>
> As of March 31, 2013, Bandai Entertainment Inc. ceased its business operations and had not being selling items for around a year.  We are unable to further respond to any email or phone inquiries regarding DVD’s.
>
> Apologies,